# What's the difference between "cozen" and "bamboozle"?

Tags: verbs, differences, obscure-terms

We have:

> cozen (verb)
>
> 1 : to deceive, win over, or induce to do something by artful coaxing and wheedling or shrewd trickery

and:

> bamboozle (verb)
>
> 1 : to deceive by underhanded methods : dupe, hoodwink. "I got bamboozled by the salesperson to buy a more expensive model."

Questions:

- Can you be cozened without having been bamboozled? Or the other way around?
- In which situations would I prefer say someone was "cozened", and in which would I prefer saying they were "bamboozled"?

Comment: I think of cozening as more low-key and subtle - the victim is being flattered and persuaded. Whereas bamboozling is more characterized by confusing and distracting the victim.

Comment: The main difference is that most people know what "bamboozle" means, but have no idea what "cozen" means.

Answer (score 1):

According to Oxford Dictionaries, *cozen* dates from the 16th century. *Bamboozle* dates from the 18th century and seems to be a humorous, slangy word. I don't think they necessarily have an official difference in meaning; there are other synonyms such as *hoodwink, take in*. I think of *cozen* as rather archaic.

Answer (score 0):

**Cozen** is all but obsolete. In the past, it was used mainly to cover **any** form of deceit - it has been replaced by to cheat or fool (someone out of something/into doing something.) Usually the verb had negative connotations.

OED
**1.a. transitive. To cheat, defraud by deceit.**

1652   P. Heylyn Cosmographie ii. sig. Ss6v   *He that trusts to a Greek is sure to be cousened.*

**To bamboozle** is current. It is not so negative. It tends to imply (i) that the deception was done by confusing the victim (ii) or simply that the person was tricked of fooled by confusion:

> MW:
>
> **Bamboozle** transitive
>
> 1 : to deceive by underhanded methods : dupe, hoodwink I got bamboozled by the salesperson to buy a more expensive model.
>
> 2 : **to confuse, frustrate, ...**
>
> *a quarterback bamboozled by an unexpected defense.*